# does ToListAsnync() work in conjunction with take()

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous

in the following

```
var formList = await _formRepository.GetList(x)
                .WhereNotHistorical()
                .OrderByDescending(f => f.dt)
                .Take(5)
                .ToListAsync();
```

since it is to list async it doesn't just return the first 5 it gets correct?  it still waits for the entire result set before ordering and taking 5. I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Please read up about the difference between `IEnumerable` Vs `IQueryable`, this will enable you to understand your repository, and draw ire at who ever wrote it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what `.GetList(x)` and `.WhereNotHistorical()` do. If they take in an `IQueryable` add to the query, and return an `IQueryable<T>`, then it should add the instructions to the SQL query to only get 5 results after ordering. IF, however, either of them take in or return an `IEnumerable<T>`, then any instructions after than will be executed in-memory, so you might get the entire result set from the database, and filtering and ordering will be done in-memory.